# How to delete table *or* view from PostgreSQL database?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I have a name of table or view in PostgreSQL database and need to delete in in single pgSQL command. How can i afford it?

I was able to select form system table to find out if there any table with such a name but stuck with procedural part:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM pg_tables where tablename='user_statistics';
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
DROP TABLE user_statistics;

DROP VIEW user_statistics;
```

complete syntax:

[DROP TABLE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.4/interactive/sql-droptable.html)

[DROP VIEW](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/sql-dropview.html)

And if you want a complete function, i tried something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION delete_table_or_view(objectName varchar) RETURNS integer AS $$
DECLARE
    isTable integer;
    isView integer;
BEGIN
    SELECT INTO isTable count(*) FROM pg_tables where tablename=objectName;
    SELECT INTO isView count(*) FROM pg_views where viewname=objectName;

    IF isTable = 1 THEN
        execute 'DROP TABLE ' || objectName;
        RETURN 1;
    END IF;

    IF isView = 1 THEN
        execute 'DROP VIEW ' || objectName;
        RETURN 2;
    END IF;

    RETURN 0;

END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Answer (score -4):

Consider using *DROP TABLE IF EXISTS* and *DROP VIEW IF EXISTS*. That way you won't get an error message if it fails, just a  notice.

Comment: That won't work actually. If you're doing `DROP VIEW IF EXISTS` and the view that you are trying to drop is actually a table than Postgres will give you an error that it is not a view (the same goes for `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS`). You need to know for sure if it's a table or a view.

Comment: DROP TABLE IF EXISTS name_of_table - to be precise