# Drop table if exists else proceed for next step in function using PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to drop table if exists else proceed for next step in function using PostgreSQL 9.3 version.

**Example**:

```
  Create or replace function test(tablename varchar)
  returns setof record as
  $$
  Declare
        var1 varchar :='table_';
  Begin
        var1 :=var1 ||tablename;
        /* Here need to drop table if exists */
       drop table if exist var1;

       /* else proceed for next step */
       ....
       ....
   end;
   $$
   language plpgsql;
```

Comment: does `drop table` works in your `Function` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [EXECUTE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-execute.html)

```
EXECUTE 'DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ' || var1;
```

Comment: Made same change. But getting only notification that table does not exists not proceeding for next procedure.

Comment: @Meem the issue is likely in your next procedure then because `IF EXISTS` is supposed to show a notification if a table does not exist, so there is nothing wrong with seeing a notification

Comment: Yes! I got it. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

You need to run the `DROP TABLE` command as below using `execute` (As @FuzzyTree already pointed much before me)

```
execute 'drop table ' || var1;
```

(OR)

```
execute 'DROP VIEW ' || var1;
```

Also another pointer, DROP TABLE is not allowed in a non-volatile function. So you may have to change the last line of your function to be

```
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' VOLATILE;
```

Check this post, Will get you better idea [How to delete table *or* view from PostgreSQL database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/463292/how-to-delete-table-or-view-from-postgresql-database)

Comment: I did. But not proceeding for next step only giving notifying that table does not exists.

Comment: No! I have used it like    "drop table if exists".

Comment: @Meem, You will have to use `IF .. ELSE` construct to conditionally do the dropping. check the link I have mentioned in answer. that will get you what you are trying to do.